# call is ambiguous between the following methods System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

My asp.net solution has a class library that targets framework **net 4.62**. I'm getting an error when I call .ToList().

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)` and `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)`

Reading through similar errors on SO, I can conclude that I have duplicate code in my files. I searched through the assembly in Object Explorer and found that they are located in both **System.Core[4.0.0.0]** and **System.Core[5.0.5.0]**.

Here's the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace PortalRepository.Implementation.Repositories
{
    public class PortalRepository<TEntity>: IPortalRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:class 
    {
        internal readonly PORTAL_Entities _context;
        internal IDbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

        private IDbSet<TEntity> Entities
        {
            set { }
            get { return _dbSet ?? (_dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>()); }
        }
        public IList<TEntity> AllEntities
        {
            set { }
            get { return Entities.ToList(); //ambiguous call here}
        }
    }
// plus other implementation of Entities and AllEntities
}
```

I am getting warnings from Visual Studio 2017 that there is "No way to resolve conflict between 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,...' and 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0,...' I thought that the above error would be related to this, but digging into Object explorer I couldn't find the method System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList() in the System.Core v3.5.0.0.  So, I'm confused.

**UPDATE**

In this project the Dependencies are:

```
-Assemblies
    *System
    *System.Core
    *System.Data
    *System.Drawing
    *System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    *System.Numerics
    *System.Runtime.Serialization
    *System.Xml
    *System.Xml.Linq
    *System.Xml.Serialization
-NuGet
    *EntityFramework(6.1.3)
```

**END UPDATE**

It has been a challenge to get this project up and going since I inherited an ASP.NET Core project and had to add .Net 4.62 class libraries to it.  My knowledge of C# is growing, but is still in its infancy.  Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Try calling the static methods instead of using the extension format.

Comment: @casey I tried using `return System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(Entities)`, but I'm getting the error that the type Enumerable is available in System.Core in both v4.0.0.0 and v3.5.0.0. Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use both .Net Core and .Net Framework in one project - I don't think that is supposed to work. You must use/reference/target one or the other.

Comment: @NetMage While I had initially tried to target both frameworks, I have  removed the .netCore reference. In the csproj file, I have `<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>`.  I'm wondering if there's a remnant of core and if so, how can I remove it.

Comment: What is in the References section of your Solution Explorer?

Comment: @NetMage Please see update for References.

Comment: Do you have references to both `System.Core` versions in your dependent assemblies in your web.config?

Comment: @codeMonkey Unfortunately in VS2017 there is only a Dependencies/Assemblies reference and it doesn't say which version of System.Core it is referencing. In object explorer, I can see both v=3.5.0.0 and 4.0.0.0, which are located in c:/user/.nuget and windows/MicrosoftNet/assemblies respectively. I believe that's the reason why the compiler is confused on which version to use.

Comment: Try running `update-package -reinstall` from the Package Manager Console. Hopefully it will resolve all your dependencies for you.

Comment: @codeMonkey Thanks! Unfortunately, I have already tried that and it didn't have any effect.  The same error still appears.

Comment: Do you have more than one project in your solution, and potentially some are .Net Core, and others are not?

Comment: @CMLee Have solved this issue?